# Pie Chart legend text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to display the label name and percentage in the legend of  pie chart that I have in VB.NET.  Below is the code.  I cannot find any library reference or code samples to lead me in the right direction that works in VB.NET. The pie chart looks and works fine except for this.

Can anyone help?

thanks

```
    PieTable.Columns.Add("Status")
    PieTable.Columns.Add("Count")
    PieTable.Rows.Add("Pass", LineCounter - FailCnt - WarningCnt)
    PieTable.Rows.Add("Fail", FailCnt)
    PieTable.Rows.Add("Warning", WarningCnt)

    OverallPieChart.DataSource = PieTable
    OverallPieChart.Width = 250
    OverallPieChart.Height = 100
    OverallPieChart.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "Status"
    OverallPieChart.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "Count"

    OverallPieChart.EnableViewState = True
    OverallPieChart.Series("Series1").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
    OverallPieChart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").BackColor = Color.Black
    OverallPieChart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True
    OverallPieChart.BackColor = Color.Black
    'OverallPieChart.Series(0)("PieLabelStyle") = "Outside (#Percent)"
    OverallPieChart.Series(0).LabelForeColor = Color.Beige
    OverallPieChart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").InnerPlotPosition.Width = 100%
    OverallPieChart.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").InnerPlotPosition.Height = 100%
    OverallPieChart.Series(0)("PieLineColor") = "Transparent"
    OverallPieChart.Series(0)("LabelsRadialLineSize") = "0.15"
    OverallPieChart.Series(0)("LabelsHorizontalLineSize") = "0.15"
    OverallPieChart.Legends.Add("Legent1")
    OverallPieChart.Legends("Legend1").Enabled = True
    OverallPieChart.Legends("Legend1").Docking = Docking.Right
    OverallPieChart.Legends("Legend1").Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Far
    OverallPieChart.Legends("Legend1").BackColor = Color.Black

    OverallPieChart.Series("Series1").IsVisibleInLegend = True
```

Comment: are you not able to show the legend in the pie chart?

Comment: What are you using to display your chart? Where are PieTable and OverallPieChart defined?

Comment: Yes.  The legend does show up, but it only displays the color and label (no value).  PieTable is define as: Dim PieTable As DataTable = New DataTable.  OverallPieChart is defined in asp.net -  ID=OverallPieChart.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
OverallPieChart.Series(0).Label = "#PERCENT"
```

Or you can use this:

```
OverallPieChart.Series(0).Label = "#PERCENT{P0}"
```

to round to the nearest whole number

For the label and the percentage:

```
OverallPieChart.Series(0)Label = "#VALX" & Environment.NewLine & "#PERCENT{P0}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code

```
OverallPieChart.Legends.Add("Legent1")
```

should be

```
OverallPieChart.Legends.Add("Legend1")
```